# Multiple for loop optimization with condition

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, iteration

I am currently looking to map a specific weight ('Poids') when a condition is satisfied (if the date falls between start and end) from one table to another.

```
Poids1 = {'ID':[1,2,3,4,5],
          'Date': ['2021-12-11', '2021-12-16', '2021-12-22', '2021-09-03', '2021-12-10'],
          'Poids':[]}
df1 = { 'ID' :[1,2,3,4,5],
        'Start Date' :['2021-12-03', '2021-12-10', '2021-12-15', '2021-08-03', '2021-12-09'],
        'End Date' :['2021-12-15', '2021-12-18', '2021-12-25', '2021-12-15', '2021-12-15'],
        'Poids' :[1,4,5,4,6]}

Poids1 = pd.Dataframe(Poids1)

df1 = pd.Dataframe(df1)
```

I have melted the Poids1 in order to have 3 Cols:

```
Poids1 = pd.melt(Poids, id_vars=['ID'])
Poids1 = Poids1.rename(columns={'variable': 'Date', 'value':'Poids'} )
Poids1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Poids1['Date'])
```

I have managed to get the result through this code:

```
for index, row in Poids1.iterrows():
    f = df1[df1['ID'] == row['ID']]
    for i, r in f.iterrows() :
        if row['Date'] >= r['Start Date'] and row['Date'] <= r['End Date']:
            Poids1.at[index, 'Poids'] = r['Poids']
```

My problem is that I got more than 130k rows in the Poids1 data frame which causes the code to run for ages.
I have tried to implement a lambda without success.
Does anyone know his way around that problem?
I am looking for something that will populate the correct 'Poids' in Poids1 if the date falls between the start and end date.

Thanks!

Comment: You should generally search for built-in pandas methods instead of iterating. In this case, you should probably be able to do it with a join.

Comment: Please check your code. A `dict` is not the same as a `pd.DataFrame`. If you try to make DataFrames of your two dicts, that fails because `Poids1['Poids']` is empty and you'll get a `ValueError: arrays must all be same length`. Then, your melt uses an undefined variable `Poids` (only `Poids1` is defined). Etc.  Also, what is the expected result?